# Retrieving correct data from WS in java

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport

I ran `wsimport` on this WSDL

http://ws.dati.comune.milano.it/opendata/wsopendata.asmx?WSDL

and generated the client-side JAX-WS classes.

Now i want to use `getOpenWifi`

using this snippet :

```
        String message = " ";
        WSOpenData wsopendata = new WSOpenData();
        GetOpenWifiResult result = wsopendata.getWSOpenDataSoap().getOpenWifi(" ");
        List<Object> list = result.getContent();
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

            message += iterator.next().toString() + " ";
        }
```

i'm obtaining `message` as

```
 [NewDataSet: null]
```

i think i'm doing something wrong, How can i retrieve the right dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I call it with SoapUI I get something like

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <getOpenWifiResponse xmlns="http://comune.milano.it/">
         <getOpenWifiResult>
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">
               <Table>
                  <ID>3</ID>
                  <Sito>Arco Della Pace</Sito>
                  <Zona>1</Zona>
                  <Attiva>1</Attiva>
                  <Codice>A0044</Codice>
                  <Coordinate>9.172460,45.475670,0.000000</Coordinate>
               </Table>
               <Table>
                  <ID>4</ID>
                  <Sito>Bastioni di Porta Nuova 23</Sito>
                  <Zona>1</Zona>
                  <Attiva>1</Attiva>
                  <Codice>E0725</Codice>
                  <Coordinate>9.192273,45.478577,0.000000</Coordinate>
               </Table>
```

I think the "NewDataSet"-Object will have subobjects "table". Check the generated artefacts (which I don´t have)

€dit: 
Try that

```
import it.milano.comune.GetOpenWifiResponse.GetOpenWifiResult;
import it.milano.comune.WSOpenData;

import java.net.URL;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WSOpenData ws = new WSOpenData(new URL("http://ws.dati.comune.milano.it/opendata/wsopendata.asmx?WSDL"));

        GetOpenWifiResult rw = ws.getWSOpenDataSoap().getOpenWifi(" ");
        for (Object o : rw.getContent()) {
            System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
            Element e = (Element) o;
            NodeList c = e.getChildNodes();

            System.out.println(c);
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getLength(); i++) {
                Node table = c.item(i);

                System.out.println("tab");

                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < table.getChildNodes().getLength(); i2++) {
                    Node property = table.getChildNodes().item(i2);
                    System.out.println("\tp: " + property);
                }

            }

        }

        long x = 1;
    }

}
```

It gave me

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
[NewDataSet: null]
tab
    p: [ID: null]
    p: [Sito: null]
    p: [Zona: null]
    p: [Attiva: null]
    p: [Codice: null]
    p: [Coordinate: null]
tab
    p: [ID: null]
    p: [Sito: null]
    p: [Zona: null]
    p: [Attiva: null]
    p: [Codice: null]
    p: [Coordinate: null]
tab
    p: [ID: null]
    p: [Sito: null]
    p: [Zona: null]
    p: [Attiva: null]
    p: [Codice: null]
    p: [Coordinate: null]
tab
    p: [ID: null]
    p: [Sito: null]
    p: [Zona: null]
    p: [Attiva: null]
    p: [Codice: null]
    p: [Coordinate: null]
[...]
```

I´m sure if you experiment a bit you´ll be able to solve it

Comment: I need to extract NewDataSet xml from getOpenWifiResult but OpenWifiResult has only List<Object> getContent() method

Comment: Bad news: i generated the stubs and did some debugging. The returned objects in the list are of type "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl". The debugger says they contain the parsed content - but I think you have to cast the types manually by yourself